# Appending new elements to a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df1:                              
    id  name   gender
    1   Alice  Male 
    2   Jenny  Female
    3   Bob    Male
```

And now I want to add a new column sport which will contain values in the form of list.Let's I want to add Football to the rows where gender is male So df1 will look like:

```
df1:                              
        id  name   gender  sport
        1   Alice  Male    [Football]
        2   Jenny  Female   NA
        3   Bob    Male    [Football]
```

Now if I want to add Badminton to rows where gender is female and tennis to rows where gender is male so that final output is:

```
df1:                              
            id  name   gender  sport
            1   Alice  Male    [Football,Tennis]
            2   Jenny  Female  [Badminton]
            3   Bob    Male    [Football,Tennis]
```

How to write a general function in python which will accomplish this task of appending new values into the column based upon some other column value?

Comment: **There is no such general function.** Or, if you choose to concoct one, it goes against the grain with Pandas by using containers as series values. Possibly, a custom class or `dict` + `list` is a more appropriate data structure choice.

Answer (score 0):

The below should work for you. Initialize column with an empty list and proceed

```
df['sport'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()

def append_sport(df, filter_df, sport):
    df.loc[filter_df, 'sport'] = df.loc[filter_df, 'sport'].apply(lambda x: x.append(sport) or x)
    return df

filter_df = (df.gender == 'Male')
df = append_sport(df, filter_df, 'Football')
df = append_sport(df, filter_df, 'Cricket')
```

Output

```
    id  name    gender  sport
0   1   Alice   Male    [Football, Cricket]
1   2   Jenny   Female  []
2   3   Bob     Male    [Football, Cricket]
```